# Should I use Sql.Stmt or string in database query in GO?

Tags: go

Hi in database/sql package I can execute a query in two ways:

- First way: using Sql.Stmt

  ```
  var DeletePermissionStmt *sql.Stmt
  DeletePermissionStmt, err = database.Prepare(`DELETE FROM permission WHERE permission_id=$1`)

  if err != nil {
       log.Errorf("can't prepare delete permission statement: %s", err.Error())
  }

  transaction, err := database.Begin()  // assume postgres database is defined previously

  if err != nil {
       log.WithFields(logFields).Errorf("can't start transaction: %s", err.Error())


  return err
  }
   _, err := transaction.Stmt(DeletePermissionStmt).Exec(permission_id)
  ```
- Second way: using string

  ```
  var DeletePermissionStmt string
  DeletePermissionStmt = `DELETE FROM permission WHERE permission_id=$1`

  transaction, err := database.Begin()  // assume postgres database is defined previously

  if err != nil {
  log.WithFields(logFields).Errorf("can't start transaction: %s", err.Error())


  return err
  }
   _, err := transaction.Exec(DeletePermissionStmt,permission_id)
  ```

The only difference That I know that its is not possible to use sql.Stmt when you are returning something for example `Insert Into FOO(f1,f2,f3) Values(v1,v2,v3) returning f_id`
Is there any other differences? and when should I use each one?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Go sql - prepared statement scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38390999/go-sql-prepared-statement-scope).

Comment: `INSERT ... RETURNING ...` is supported if you use `tx.QueryRow()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Stmt helps you avoid sql injection from the user.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement):

> Prepared statements are resilient against SQL injection, because
>   parameter values, which are transmitted later using a different
>   protocol, need not be correctly escaped. If the original statement
>   template is not derived from external input, SQL injection cannot
>   occur.